# cd to a directory with easybuild

Tags: build

I'm trying to write my first easyconfig file (for Gadget2). Once untarred, the source of Gadget2 contains a directory named Gadget2, so I need to instruct easybuild to cd to that directory. Is this possible or I need to write my own easyblock? I'm using the easyblock MakeCp.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ward Poelmans gave me the answer through the eb mailling:

There is a variable for this purpose:

```
start_dir
```